# c# wpf define local hotkey for start a function

Tags: c#, wpf, input, hotkeys, inputbinding

i need to define some hotkeys that allows me to start some little functions, but i tried to use InputBinding that needs to use a commands and CommandBinding, are there some other methods? i just only want to call a function.

Comment: What's wrong with commands? It's a common practice in WPF to react on UI events with commands.

Comment: Right approach is to use command binding (**yes, even to call a simple function**). You may derive your own `RoutedCommand` or use a simpler `RelayCommand`. That said if it's just for debugging...you still can handle `KeyUpEvent` in your window...